# Gef connection endpoints location update as editpart is moved

Tags: eclipse-gef

I have an editpart's to which connections are made.  When the editpart location is changed the connection endpoints also must update their location, and also the connection to the editparts must occur only to the four sides of the rectangle. Can can any one advice me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the location of the endpoints is fairly easy: The interface `org.eclipse.draw2d.Connection` defines methods for assigning source and target anchors. Ensure that in your `Connection` implementation you attach an `AnchorListener` to the anchors, when they are set. When `anchorMoved(...)` is called, you can revalidate (and repaint) the connection (`PolylineConnection` provides a good default implementation - have a look at it).

To define, where the connection should connect visually, you must provide your implementation of `org.eclipse.draw2d.ConnectionAnchor` in the `getSourceConnectionAnchor(...)` and `getTargetConnectionAnchor(...)` methods of your shape edit part.